# Are there common "phrases" in complex Mathematical notation?

Tags: notation, soft-question, formal-grammar

More precisely, are there **complex** mathematical-notation-patterns that convey more meaning to somebody who's seen and understood them before, than they do to somebody who's just seen them? (Even if the person just seeing them understands all the notation.)

To give an example of a **simple** phrase, in probability, $|$ means "given", and $P(.)$ means the probability of whatever takes the place of the dot. Taken together $P(X|Y)$ means "The probability of $X$ given $Y$". This could be considered a simple mathematical phrase.

Personally, I don't have to think about what it means because I've seen it before. But it might take somebody who hasn't seen it a non-trivial amount of time to understand it.

At a post graduate level, are there a greater number of far more complex phrases that you have to memorise to be fluent in maths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practitioners in any branch of mathematics  build a vocabulary of terms that encapsulate abstractions. Those terms might be natural language or more formal mathematical expressions. Then they communicate using those terms. Newcomers to the field gradually learn  the local language. That isn't primarily memorizing complex phrases, it's becoming fluent.

Augmenting language this way is not limited to mathematics, or even to technical fields. Every sport or religion or government or corporation does it.

**Edit** in response to this comment from the OP:

> I'm a material science Post-Doc, so perhaps not as far removed as my
> comments are suggesting. At the very least, I'm definitely not a PhD
> program away from understanding the papers. My question was prompted
> by some papers in game theory, which I'm interested in understanding
> for practical reasons - Explainable AI. In one paper there was an
> innocent, short mathematical phrase that I didn't think much of. Then,
> looking deeper, it seemed that the phrase was actually a short way of
> saying something complex. My question is intended to discover how
> common this is.

I think you may have asked an [xy question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Rather than wondering how common it is for mathematicians to pack a lot into a single formal statement you can ask about the particular statements that puzzle you. one at a time on this site. Show us your best effort and the background you bring and why the meaning matters and we may be able to help.

Comment: Thank you, is there a name for these sub-languages in maths? And what's the fastest way to become fluent in the language of a particular sub-field?

Comment: There's no name for this particular kind of vocabulary building. The way to become fluent in a new language is to read and write and speak it a lot. (That said, some parts of mathematics have a longer learning curve. I have personally preferred areas where the ratio of definitions to theorems is relatively low.)

Comment: Okay, how do you go about picking up the vocabulary that's hidden in obscure texts? Also, how do you go about understanding some of the more complex phrases of pure mathematical notation in a sub-field? Is it a question of digging through papers to find the original source who explains fully why they use it? Does that mean you prefer theorems over definitions?

Comment: You read papers - look for well written ones.  You ask professors and fellow students when you're puzzled. You write yourself notes. Understanding the material and understanding the vocabulary come together. (I think every mathematician prefers theorems to definitions. I prefer those theorems that are easier to state without needing a lot  of preliminary definitions. So combinatorics rather than algebraic geometry.)

Comment: What defines a well written paper? Are they usually the ones that are easier to understand? Or the ones with the most consistent and precise notation? I agree, I feel like understanding the vocabulary is the first step to understanding the material, is that the way it works in your experience?

Comment: @Connor "Also, how do you go about understanding some of the more complex phrases" This seems like the wrong way to approach things. You don't understand mathematical language by attacking it head on. If you want to learn some field, you work through intro books/courses and then advanced books and courses and then fundamental papers in the subfield that people point you to or that are commonly cited, (and maybe work through some new stuff to gain fluency and maybe get a PhD), and then you are able or maybe a paper or two away from reading whatever cutting-edge notation/terminology.

Comment: @MarkS. I agree that approaching a topic from start to finish is the best way to gain fluency, but it's also a huge time investment. If you're interested in the conclusions of a series of papers, and you need to understand them in the next 2 weeks, it's not practical to get a PhD first. I find myself in that situation frequently, and whilst I am learning more and more about maths, I have serious time constraints. You've hit upon the hidden purpose of the question though. I'm interested in figuring out a way to shortcut the process through pattern recognition.

Comment: @Connor For most of math, if you *think* you're interested in the conclusions of a series of papers, but are an entire PhD program away from understanding them, then you probably don't understand the context well enough for your interest to be meaningful. And no shortcut will cut two years down to two weeks. I can't imagine what circumstances would require you to understand distant math papers in two weeks "or else" (assuming you're not currently a grad student or something), but I guess I'd say "do all you can to see if there's another way" and "pay someone to tutor you if at all poassible".

Comment: @MarkS. I'm a material science Post-Doc, so perhaps not as far removed as my comments are suggesting. At the very least, I'm definitely not a PhD program away from understanding the papers. My question was prompted by some papers in game theory, which I'm interested in understanding for practical reasons - Explainable AI. In one paper there was an innocent, short mathematical phrase that I didn't think much of. Then, looking deeper, it seemed that the phrase was actually a short way of saying something complex. My question is intended to discover how common this is.

Comment: @MarkS. Could you define "meaningful interest"?

Comment: @Connor, thanks for clarifying. The context changes your question quite a bit. If you can't find a digestible explanation of the phrase elsewhere online, you could post a StackExchange question or similar explaining what you've read and what gaps you need filled in. With "meaningful interest", I was imagining a very different scenario of non-applied math where someone is much further away. Someone who knows no topology can't meaningfully say they're interested in a paper on Adams Spectral Sequence calculations because they can't distinguish that from the more-vague "something to analyze shapes